# Cropping and inserting image with irregular shape using mouse

Tags: javascript, html

I have already cropped an image in an irregular shape. I need to insert an image into the cropped part. I have used HTML5 and JavaScript (kinetic.js) to do this (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLjcM.jpg). I have done the area plotting. I don't want shapes like rect, poly etc. I need a user-defined shape and should be cropped using mouse.

Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: I don't think there is any code showing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [compositing settings](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/) of the 2d context. These allow you to use a path or an image to perform masking on a canvas. When you `.fillPath` the path you created above with a solid `fillColor` and `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'`, the path will not be drawn and only those parts of the image will remain which are covered by the interior of the path. The rest will be alpha-transparent. When you use the `'source-out'` operation instead, you create a transparent "hole" in the canvas you draw the path to.

So when you have a canvas with the source image (the image you want to insert), a canvas with the destination image (the image you want to insert the other image into) and the path, there are thee ways to do it.

a) you draw the path to the source canvas with `source-in`, so you have a graphic in the correct shape on it. Then you set the composite operation back to `source-over` and then `drawImage` the source canvas onto the destination canvas. This will crop the image on the source canvas, so make sure to create a copy beforehand when you still need it.

b) you draw the path to the destination image with `destination-out` to erase the area enclosed by the path, set the composite operation to `destination-atop` and then `drawImage` the source image to the destination image, which will then be inserted "behind" the transparent parts of the destination. This variant is non-destructive for the source canvas. Remember to set the globalCompositeOperation back to `source-over` when you are finished, or other canvas operations might no longer do what you expect them to do.

c) Just like in b) you use `destination-out` to cut a hole into the destination canvas, but then you set the composite operation to the normal setting `source-over` and draw the destination onto the source. You now have the completed image on the source canvas.